# Find duplicates from two keys array and sum different keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have array:

```
$array = [
  0 => [
    0 => 1500
    1 => 994
    2 => 155
    3 => 530
  ]
  1 => [
    0 => 1500
    1 => 994
    2 => 9314
    3 => 11
  ]
  2 => [
    0 => 25
    1 => 5
    2 => 63
    3 => 47
  ]
  3 => [
    0 => 1500
    1 => 994
    2 => 3
    3 => 51
  ]];
```

And if `$array[key][0]` and `$array[key][1]` has same values, then I need to sum `$array[key][2]` and `$array[key][3]` only on duplicated `$array[key][0]` and `$array[key][1]` and combine into one key.

That's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$array = [
  0 => [
    0 => 1500
    1 => 994
    2 => 9472
    3 => 592
  ]
  1 => [
    0 => 25
    1 => 5
    2 => 63
    3 => 47
  ]];
```

First and second values (1500 and 994) have to be unchanged.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [
  0 => [
    0 => 1500,
    1 => 994,
    2 => 155,
    3 => 530,
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => 1500,
    1 => 994,
    2 => 9314,
    3 => 11,
  ],
  2 => [
    0 => 25,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 63,
    3 => 47,
  ],
  3 => [
    0 => 1500,
    1 => 994,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 51,
  ],];


  // create composite array key 

  $newArray = [];
  foreach($array as $item) {
      $compositeKey = $item[0] . '-' . $item[1];
      $newArray[$compositeKey] = [
          $item[0],
          $item[1],
          isset($newArray[$compositeKey][2]) ? $newArray[$compositeKey][2] + $item[2] : $item[2],
          isset($newArray[$compositeKey][3]) ? $newArray[$compositeKey][3] + $item[3] : $item[3],
          ];
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r(array_values($newArray));
  echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1500
            [1] => 994
            [2] => 9472
            [3] => 592
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 63
            [3] => 47
        )

)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/940f06c43338d9785b7c47548a0dcbf6e4b2cd75